# Antlr4 - representing syntactic predicates that examine arbitrary number of tokens

Tags: java, c++, parsing, antlr4, antlr3

In Antlr3, I have the following grammar:

```
ruleA:
    (ruleBStart) => ruleB
    | ruleC
;
```

For the sake of simplicity let's assume ruleB is the grammar for SELECT statement in SQL, but could be nested in an arbitrary number of LPARENs. This is easy to represent in old grammar by simply saying:

```
ruleBStart:
    (LPAREN)* SELECT
;
```

In Antlr4, if I wanted to do the same thing, I would write a semantic predicate `isRuleBStart()` which may look like this (pseudocode):

```
@parser::members{
    public boolean isRuleBStart(int tokenNum)
    {
        int token = _input.LA(tokenNum);
        if (token == EOF) return false; // handling EOF probably needs more work
        if (token == SELECT) return true;
        if (token == LPAREN) return isRuleBStart(tokenNum++);
        return false;
    }
}
```

And then in my grammar, I would do:

```
ruleA:
    {isRuleBStart(1)}? ruleB
    | ruleC
;
```

This appears problematic to me since:

1. It involves recursion in a construct that is already *rumored* to be performance degrading
2. `ruleBStart` could get much more complicated if the ruleBStart rule had an arbitrary set of different tokens to check instead of just repeating LPAREN
3. It binds my code to target language. So if I wanted to publish a parser in Java and C++, I would have to re-implement this semantic predicate in both. (I know it is possible to carefully program the semantic predicate so the same code works in Java and C++, but that is not the point).

So I want to ask the community if there is a right Antlr4 way to achieve the same result.

Comment: Is the "rule-start-thingy" just an example or your actual problem? Because if it's your real problen it shouldn't be hard to get rid of the predicate by refactoring the grammar

Comment: @Raven, That's how the Antlr3 grammar is written. I need to convert to Antlr4, so refactoring in Antlr3 won't solve my problem. I don't have to use ruleBStart in Antl4 and would ideally not want to, if at all possible.

Comment: @Raven, but I do need to retain ruleB (maybe a refactored ruleB, but can't get rid of a rule called ruleB completely since it has other references elsewhere in the grammar. Hope that clarifies.

Comment: The thing is that what you are doing in your semantic predicate could be achieved in the grammar itself without the need of a predicate at all. Therefore the question whether that check is just an example and your real check differs (in which case refactoring might not solve the problem) or if this is indeed the "real problem". In that case refactoring the grammar should eliminate the need for that predicate.

Comment: I don't follow. If you had the opportunity, how would you refactor the code to eliminate the predicate?

Comment: Make `ruleB` start with `LPAREN? SELECT` and there you go... As long as the condition you are checking in your code is not fullfilled the rule won't be matched

Comment: I see what you mean. That path is unfortunately not available to me. Hence the original question: given a syntactic predicate that examines n arbitrary tokens to decide on a path is there a clean way of representing that logic in a semantic predicate.

Answer (score 1):

There's no need for a semantic predicate with ANTLR4. The ALL(*) algorithm will do an unlimited lookahead, if needed and hence doesn't need semantic predicates or any comparable hack.

So, just remove that predicate and everything should just work.

Comment: there *is* a need for semantic predicates. Let's suppose ruleB was built in functions and ruleC was user defined functions. Built in functions have a well defined signature, but user defined functions could have any signature (with maybe only minimal constraints of arbitrary number of expressions within brackets. If I didn't have semantic predicates, an ill-formed built in function call would get parsed as a user defined function. I use the semantic predicate to ensure that the parser always takes the built in function subrule and fails rather than parse it as user defined function.

Comment: How can you know that an "ill-formed" built-in function wasn't actually meant to be a user defined function? IMO a built-in function can only be that if it is syntactically correct. Any derivation **is** a user defined function per se.

Comment: I know what you mean, but the requirement of my project is that a built in function should fail if it doesn't have the right signature and it should not be parsed as a user defined function. So unfortunately, I had to create a start rule based semantic predicate "hack" (as you call it). Essentially, this takes you off the nice "auto-pilot" that LL* provides, but looks like that is the only way to deliver what is being asked of me.

Comment: This is semantics that should not be dealt with by the parser. In your semantic phase after parsing you can check if a user function looks like a built-in one and give precise error info, if that's the case. Much better than letting the parser issue an error like "No viable alt".

Comment: That's a good thought Mike. Unfortunately, the old grammar has a test suite that expects fails to tokenize / parse in a certain way and I need to reproduce the same effect for the tests to pass. I think if I had the latitude to do this afresh, I would have avoided semantic predicates completely like you suggest. I tried many "after the fact" manipulations that show encouraging results, till they meet their match in some test case and then they fail hard. I think the idea of doing this after the parse phase has merits; might be worth revisiting again. Thank you for all your help and insights :)

Comment: Just a thought: why not change the test cases if they no longer are useful as they are?

Comment: So the test cases represent how client applications expect to get an output from this library that I'm looking to publish as a drop in replacement for the older parser. The expectation from client application team is that the upgrade would not cause a change in their code. Hence the need to conform to the unit tests. I know it's a hard path, but I'm already committed to it... on the bright side, it makes you learn Antlr internals like your life depended on it :)